# "Forbidden" when getting Direct Messages with twython

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth, twython

```
twitter = twython.Twython(oauth_token        = oauth_token,
                          oauth_token_secret = oauth_secret,
                          app_key            = oauth_consumer_key,
                          app_secret         = oauth_consumer_secret)
twitter.getDirectMessages()

TwythonError: 'Forbidden: The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits. -- An error occurred processing your request.'
```

I am using the tokens, secrets, and keys shown on my My Applications page on dev.twitter.com, under the "Details" tab.  I'm a little concerned that twython calls it app_key, while twitter calls it a consumer_key.  Maybe I've got things confused / backwards.

Other calls, like twitter.getFriendsIDs() succeed.

Comment: This might be germane.  I just tried twitter.updateStatus(status='asdf') and got an error: TwythonError: u'Unauthorized: Authentication credentials were missing or incorrect. -- Read-only application cannot POST' -- however, I have changed my application to be read and write

Comment: I found the answer here:
https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/718